# how to make several views into 1 view mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-view

[image]

based on that picture, there's a buyer data who do transaction in same period, example like the first one there's **29** buyer who do transaction between 1 july - 30 sep 2017 and between 1 apr - 30 june 2017, with this syntax

```
CREATE VIEW sum_ba as (SELECT 
    b.buyer_id
FROM order_buyer b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2017-04-01' AND d.createdAt < '2017-07-01') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2017-04-01' AND d.createdAt < '2017-07-01' ) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
                WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND d.createdAt < '2017-04-01') group by buyer_id);
```

and it was right, but how do i make view for all the transaction in period 1 july 2017-30 sept 2017 so the value of **3098** appear too.

the result who i expected is when i launch the view of 1 july 2017-30 sept 2017, and it become **29 buyers from 1 apr-30jun 2017** , **3098 new buyers in 1 july 2017-30 sept 2017** and the total is **3127 buyers in 1 july 2017 until 30 sept 2017**

Comment: Step back a bit, tell us where this data comes from publish the table definitions involved and sample data of a small but representative and manageable size.

Comment: the data was data buyer from 2017 untill 2019, it contains buyer_id and createdAt which the buyer doing transaction, the data type is date in createdAt was timestamp and buyer_id was int(10)

Comment: There is nothing in the question which suggests to me when an order was paid..